# Azure DevOps run build on branch creation

Tags: azure-devops

My pipeline looks like:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - release-*

jobs:
- job: release
  condition: contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release-')
  pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'
  steps:
  - bash: |
      echo "RELEASE"
    displayName: 'release_task1'
```

How can I make it executed automatically when new `release-..` branch is created?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I make it executed automatically when new release-.. branch is created?

This is a limitation of YAML trigger.

If the yaml file is not present in the new create branch, the build will not be triggered.

That is reason why it does not execute automatically when creating a new `release ...` branch.

To resolve this issue, we need to create the yaml file in the basic branch, like `release-basic`, then we create a new branch based on the branch `release-basic`. Now the build will be executed automatically.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have `develop` branch which contains `release/*` as a trigger in yaml pipeline; When I create `release/` branch from `develop` it still not triggered automatically on creation, but when I push some changes to `release/` it works